# trying to execute git command using python script

Tags: python, git

I am trying to execute a simple git command using following python script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import commands
import subprocess
import os
import sys

pr = subprocess.Popen( "/usr/bin/git log" , cwd = os.path.dirname( '/ext/home/rakesh.kumar/workspace/myproject' ), shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE )
(out, error) = pr.communicate()


print "Error : " + str(error) 
print "out : " + str(out)
```

but I am getting the following error even though I am running the python script in the same directory where git reposetory is.

```
Error : fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

I suspected the git might got correputed, but git files are fine and git commands work if I execute on normal command prompt.

I tried to search on net but couldn't get useful information. Please help it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with code that wraps at 79 chars ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import commands
import subprocess
import os
import sys

pr = subprocess.Popen( "/usr/bin/git log" , cwd = os.path.dirname( '/ext/home/rakesh.kumar/workspace/myproject/' ), shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE )
(out, error) = pr.communicate()


print "Error : " + str(error) 
print "out : " + str(out)
```

Directory path should have '/' at the end.

Comment: Note that this error can also occur if you have the `GIT_DIR` environment variable set (particularly to a relative path, as can happen in git hooks)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is your use of `os.path.dirname()`:

```
os.path.dirname( '/ext/home/rakesh.kumar/workspace/myproject' )
```

will give you:

```
>>> os.path.dirname( '/ext/home/rakesh.kumar/workspace/myproject' )
'/ext/home/rakesh.kumar/workspace'
```

which, I bet, is not what you want.